# mocha chai how to add custom headers based on a condition

Tags: mocha.js, chai

Tried searching in google and mocha docs, no hints. Any hints for my question will be great.

Say in below test case I have two headers

1. how to have if condition in mocha chai
2. based on the if condition i need to add or remove the headers

say

```
if (token === 'a') 
  set app_id header 
else 
  set authorization header
end
```

Actual request::

```
request(app)
      .post('/api/categories')
      .send(category)
      .set({app_id: app123})
      .set({ Authorization: token })
      .end((err, res) => {
       done();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below fixed my confusions.

1. Having a `before{}` helped me to have if conditions and set variable
2. And accessing this variable in `.set` in mocha test